# Why isn't my CSS working in IE 8 and IE 7?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser, internet-explorer-7

What in this CSS doesn't work in IE8 & IE7?

```
nav {
position: fixed;
top:60px;
left:30px;
color:black;
float:left;
}
nav div#button {
    width:205px;
    height:50px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top:  5px;
    margin-bottom:10px; 
    font-size: 23px;
}
nav a {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
nav div#button:active  {
    width:250px;
    height:65px;
}
nav div#button.home {
    background-color: #79b22c;
}
nav div#button.links {
    background-color: #3b50cc;
}
nav div#button.aanbod {
    background-color: #BA3BCC;
}
nav div#button.forum {
    background-color: #1CAEB2;
}
nav div#button.contact {
    background-color: #daa520;
}
```

It works fine in IE9 & IE10. But IE8 & IE7 displays no-styled text.
I have tested with browserstack. 
 Who can help me please?

Comment: `nav div#button` raises some concerns. In your markup, how many elements have `id="button"`?

Comment: 5 elements with 'id="button"'

Comment: IDs should be unique to a single element within the entire `<html>` document. You shouldn't have more than 1 `id="button"`. If you need to reuse on multiple elements, use a `class` name instead -- `class="button"` and `class="button home"`.

Comment: The `nav` element [isn't supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nav).

Comment: <nav> tag is html5 tag and it's can't working IE7, IE8...

Answer (score 2):

`<nav>` and other HTML5 elements were defined after IE 7 and IE 8 were released, so the browsers aren't aware of how to handle them.

They can, however, be instructed to handle them. And, the [`html5shiv`](https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv#readme) can help with this:

> Include the HTML5 shiv at the top of your `<head>` in a conditional comment after any stylesheets.
>
> ```
> <!--[if lt IE 9]>
>     <script src="html5shiv.js"></script>
> <![endif]-->
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Also you don't need:

`div#menu` You need `#menu`

At the top of your code

Comment: can i see what your page looks like as is and what it is meant to look like

Answer (score 0):

Delete color and just use background

Answer (score 0):

Position: fixed not work in ie7. Use should use expression() for this in css and position absolute.